# QTranslator checking

Tags: qt

How to check which file with translation was loaded ? (Current loaded translation)
I load translation in main.c and I would like to check in MainWindow Class which translation was loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it, using Qt's methods.

The best way of doing it would be to write a wrapper around `QTranslator` and store all loaded translation files in it (you can load more than one translation file at a time).

Much worse, but easier way is to use a fake translation. Something like this:

```
const QString check = tr("lang");
if (check == "en") {
    // it's english
} else if (check == "fr") {
    // it's french
}
...
```

Comment: That's actually a great idea!

Comment: I have the information in file but I open and read it only in main.c
I do not want to open the file in MainWindow Class as well How to forward the information to MainWindow Class

Comment: You could change MainWindow's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Internationalization with Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/internationalization.html), you anyway get the system locale to load the appropriate translation file. Just check the value of the locale string:

```
#include <QLocale>

QString locale = QLocale::system().name();
```

For example, for English, it is "en", for German - "de".

Comment: Unfortunately It does not work because I have locale EN but I want to have application in DE.